# Using std::optional in a C++11 context

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, nullptr, stdoptional

I'm writing a small C++11 library in which I believe `std::optional` would be a nice addition in some functions which can return `nullptr`. However, `std::optional` is a C++17 feature. Since being C++11 is a requirement, I'm looking for ways to use `std::optional` while keeping compatibility.

I found that [feature macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros#C.2B.2B17) can be tested. I suppose I could use it to detect whether `std::optional` is available... but what's the best approach when it isn't?

Should I provide my own `std::optional` implementation?

Return `nullptr` when `std::optional` isn't available? (Likely to mess my code.)

Or give up on the idea and keep returning `nullptr` only?

Comment: What about `boost::optional`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Possible, but I'd rather keep the library depending only on the STL itself.

Comment: If C++11 is a requirement, you cannot use `std::optional`. Choose one.

Comment: You can always make your own.  AFAIK it does not rely on any C++17 features, it just wasn't added until then.

Comment: Another thing you can do is use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Why, `std::optional` is not that complex. Find some reliable implementation and/or write some template code. You won't get that class from anywhere else in C++11.

Comment: If you have code that works correctly without `std::optional` just use it. Don’t complicate things with maybe-this-way-maybe-that-way.

Comment: IMHO the question is if you want to return something (an object) that is on the heap or if you want to retrun a value (not created on the heap - here optional helps). If you only need to support heap objects you could mimic the optional API with a wrapper that uses `std::unique_ptr`. (_Note: my company used a std::optional backport to C++11, so it is possible to use it with C++11._)

Comment: @Mas "Not that complex" [1500 lines](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard way of using `std::optional` in C++11. You can either depend on C++17, or you cannot use `std::optional`.

> Should I provide my own std::optional implementation?

You can write your own optional implementation, but you cannot call it `std::optional`. Alternatively, you can use a pre-existing implementation such as the one in Boost.

All that said, if you're returning a pointer anyway, then  there is probably not much point in using optional since pointers already have a representation for "empty" value: the null pointer. If however you need to distinguish null from empty, then optional may be useful.

Answer (score 4):

use this header: https://github.com/TartanLlama/optional

It is the equivalent of std::optional. But it works on C++11 also.
When you upgrade to C++17, switch your code to `#include <optional>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not make return type dependent on C++ Standard version.
Standard version switches are meant to be able to compile different parts of a program with different values.
If you behave differently based on this, you'll break ODR.