# Is there a "return NULL" equivalent for return-by-reference functions?

Tags: c++, reference, return-value, return-by-reference

I'm working with existing code that returns a reference, something like this:

```c
int &func()
{
   static int i = 5;
   return i;
}
```

I would like to return an error case as "NULL" but of course NULL doesn't work in a return-by-reference function.  If this were returning a pointer I might do this:

```c
int *func()
{
   static int i = 5;

   if (!good)
       return NULL;
   else
       return &i;
}
```

Besides converting to a pointer-based return value, is there a best practice for returning a failure state?

Comment: References can't be `nullptr` - that's kind of the whole idea (mostly) of references vs pointers. So *no*. Also, don't use `NULL` in modern C++.

Comment: You can also can kind of think of references as pointers that must point to a valid object.

Comment: Returning null or anything like it defeats about nine tenths of the point of references. Look into `std::optional` as an alternative.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, this might also be a good place to throw an exception.

Comment: @user4581301, I thought of that too...but the code isn't conducive to throwing at this point, for "reasons"

Comment: Not a worry. For all I know the failure case wouldn't be exceptional enough to be worth the overhead of exception handling. It's good low-hanging fruit to throw out there, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, c++17 introduced [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), which can be empty, but it cannot have a reference so `std::optional<<std::reference_wrapper<int>>` is the proper "standard" return.

```cpp
std::optional<<std::reference_wrapper<int>> func()
{

   static int i = 5;

   if (!good)
       return std::nullopt;  // return {}; works here
   else
       return i;
}
```

later c++20 introduced [std::expected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected) which can also return an `Error Type` to signal more information than just a "failure".

even if you are using older c++ standards you can still use [optional in c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598241/using-stdoptional-in-a-c11-context) libraries, same as [expected in c++11](https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected) libraries.

---

[c++11 optional library](https://github.com/TartanLlama/optional) can hold a reference, so you can use it for cleaner code.

```
tl::optional<int&> func()
{

   static int i = 5;

   if (!good)
       return tl::nullopt;  // return {}; works here
   else
       return i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::optional<T>` cannot take a reference type, so `std::optional<int&>` is invalid. I'd recommend returning a pointer here, and setting it to `nullptr` in the error case. It is Good and Valid C++ to return a non-owning pointer.

```
int* func()
{

   static int i = 5;

   if (!good)
       return nullptr;
   else
       return &i;
}
```

Comment: `nullptr` is a keyword, not a member of  `std`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::optional` seems to be what you're looking for. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional